# Install django-extensions in requirements.pip

Tags: python, django, pip, django-extensions

I am working in a team of programmers. I would like to install `werkzeug` and `django-extensions` in our main Django project. I know I have to insert something confusing for me in requirement.pip in such a way we could simply do `pip install -r requirements.py`. Could anyone have an idea what do I have to insert in that file?

Comment: Insert the packages you want to install. E.g.
`django == 1.6.8
dj-database-url == 0.3.0
gunicorn == 19.3.0`. There must be a new line in between the package names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip uses what's known as a requirements file, this is usually a text file and it's most unusual to name it as requirements.pip or requirements.py. The file just contains a list of packages that will be installed by pip when invoked as

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

more details here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files. IN your case your file would look like

```
django-extensions
Werkzeug
```

Of course you can get fancy and include exact versions or minimum versions, exact versions etc. Most often requirements files are generated by

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

to ease setting up similar virtualenvs on different servers.

Comment: Do I need to install the version of django-extenisons and Werkzeug? For install, django-extenisons=1.1.0 and Werkzeug=1.1.0?

Comment: If you want to specify the exact version you can do so but it's option. But note that it should be `==` and not `=` when you do

Comment: Usual practice when installing anything is to install the latest version and that's what happen if you do not specify any version information.

Comment: Usually `django-extensions` is not a requirement of the project. `requirements.txt` should only contain only project requirements, not development tools.